# Reloading a page won't work after calling a javaScript alert in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a `contact-us` page in my site. 
When user submits a form it will go to  `mailIt.php` and do the necessary to send that mail. After sending that it will refresh the code.

Since I wanted to add notification kinda thing to notify the user that the mail has been sent, I changed the code to display a javaScript alert in the page. But after that alert will be shown and the **page loading will stop** and it will remain in the `mailIt.php` page (with `inout` text).

```
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Thank you for contacting us!");
    </script>
<?php
echo("in");
header('Location: /contact_us.html');   
echo("out");
```

The only part I added is  the,

```
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon !");
    </script>
<?php
```

Why is this happening ? How can I prevent that ?

Answer (score 0):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

You are sending the javascript pop up before you call the `header()` function.

A solution would be to print the javascript popup and then load the contents of ./contact_us.html and print that to your page, like so:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Thank you for contacting us!");
</script>';

$html = file_get_contents('./contact_us.html');
echo $html;
```

And if you want to be sure the mail has been sent, you should put the `mail()` function in a `if()` statement. `mail()` returns a bool: true if succeeded and false if failed.

```
if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Thank you for contacting us!");
    </script>';

    $html = file_get_contents('./contact_us.html');
    echo $html;
}
else{
    echo 'Oops, something went wrong!';
}
```